# Why does $ \lim\limits_{x\to2}(-1/2)^x$ not exist?

Tags: limits

$$ \lim\limits_{x\to2}(-1/2)^x=1/4$$
My teacher says this is not correct, and I just can't fathom why this is not correct. I tried to find the value of the given function in the neighbourhood of $2$, and I got this

[image]

Now I can't understand why my calculator is giving these weird results.
are $(-1/2)^{1.92}$ and $(-1/2)^{192/100}$ different
and does this limit really not exist?

Comment: How do you define power with negative base?

Comment: no idea! plz go on explain it to me

Comment: Your calculator is using complex numbers. It is also computing decimal powers using a logarithm, but computing rational powers by doing the integer power of the numerator and the integer root of the denominator; as $(-1/2)^{192}$ is a positive number, we can take its 100th root safely without complex numbers. $(-1/2)^{1.92}$ invites your calculator to dip into complex numbers; a thing that people often find weird at first is that the same number *can have different powers* in the complex realm

Comment: "My teacher says this is not correct, and I just can't fathom why this is not correct."  Ask your teacher to explain.

Comment: so then (-1/2)^1.92 is a real number, right? and of course if we want we can have complex solutions to that as well, but we can safely say here that (-1/2)^1.92 is a real number. is what i am saying correct?

Comment: @WGuru, "$(-1/2)^{1.92}$ is a real number?" The correct answer is that, (1) it can assume any of the 25 different complex values (depending on the definition), and (2) only one of them is real. Now the issue is that, you **can't** define $(-1/2)^x$ so that it is both real-valued and continuous. You must give up at least one of these two properties, and if you want to retain many nice properties about exponential, you need to give up real-valuedness. Now, using the principal complex logarithm, we have $$(-1/2)^x=\exp(x(-\log 2 + i\pi)),$$ and this version satisfies $(-1/2)^x\to1/4$ as $x\to2$.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee  I want (-1/2)^(x) to be real, I dont care about continuity as I am only interested in evaluating the limit. so now how will we say limit exist without using principal complex logarithm

Comment: To emphasize... for a limit $\lim\limits_{x\to c} f(x)$ to exist and equal some limit $L$, we require every subsequence $f(x_n)$ to satisfy $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(x_n) = L$ for every sequence $x_n$ such that $x_n\to c$.  Depending on how you are interpreting your exponentials here... compare the following two subsequences that you could approach $x=2$ from the top with:  $\frac{5}{2}, \frac{9}{4}, \frac{13}{6},\frac{17}{8},\dots$ and $\frac{8}{3},\frac{12}{5},\frac{16}{7},\frac{20}{9},\dots$.  Each of these subsequences could very well have $f(x_n)$ be approaching two different limits.

Comment: @Jmoravitz  if I say that we are only dealing in real numbers then both of those sequences will not be in the domain of the function, so then your argument will fail, so does the limit exist now??

Comment: If you choose $(-1/2)^x$ to be real for any rational $x$ (since it cannot take a real value when $x$ is irrational), then this version of exponential is discontinuous everywhere, and the limit $\lim_{x\to2}(-1/2)^x$ **does not exist**. (This is essentially what JMoravitz is explaining about.)

Comment: @Sangchul Lee f(x)=(-1/2)^(x) ok let this function be discontinuous. but there could be a function that is  discontinuous everywhere but its limit still does exist. what I am  trying to say here is since when did continuty become a creatiria for existence of limit

Comment: @SangchulLee that formula requires $q$ odd.

Comment: To check a suspicion of mine, what do you get from your calculator if you use 194 instead of 192?

Comment: @eyeballfrog, That is true, it seems quite pesky to give a reasonable definition of real-valued exponential. I will delete my comment and try to come up with a more reasonable answer.

Comment: I will tell you why existence of limit seems to be a strong possibility for me - 1.92, 1.984 . I have found these two numbers for which (-1/2)^(x) gives real values and both are getting closer to 1/4 , similiarly we can find more such numbers for which function gives real values closer and closer to 1/4. so we have found a sequence for which f(x) converges to 1/4. now I get it this is not enough to claim existence of limit but we clearly can also not claim limit doesnt not exit,

Comment: this problem is really bothering me, I desperately need to understand how we can say limit doesnot exist

Comment: in my comment f(x)=(-1/2)^(x)

Comment: No idea how such "pathological" cases are handled , but I would consider a function not being defined in any neighborhood of some point (except the point itself) not to have a limit at this point.

Comment: @peter I dont understand what you are trying to say mate but f(x)=(-1/2)^(x) is defined at atleast one point in  every neighborhood of 2. so 2 is a cluster point so therefore we can talk about limit of f(x) at 2

Comment: But I would demand that there is a neighborhood in which the function is defined everywhere (perhaps except the point). Otherwise , "limit" is a strange formulation. It is possible that "officially" , this is not necessary. I was surprised as well that we cannot say that a function is discontinous where it is not defined. I learnt this different.

Comment: @peter I would disagree with you mate, I dont think function has to be defined everywhere in some neighborhood of 2 for us to talk about limit at 2,( if I am wrong please correct me)

Comment: Seems that the below answer is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us define the "real-valued" exponential $f$ as the partial function given by

$$ f(x) = [\text{unique real value among $(-1/2)^x = e^{x\log(-1/2)}$} ], $$

where $\log(z) = \log|z| + i(2\pi k + \arg(z))$ is the multivalued complex logarithm. Now there are several observations:

1. $f(x)$ can only possibly defined if $x$ is rational.
2. If $x = p/q$ is a rational number in lowest terms, then we can prove that the set
   $$\{e^{(p/q)\log(-1/2)} = (1/2)^{p/q}e^{(2k+1)\pi i p/q} : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$
   contains exactly one real number if $q$ is odd, and no real numbers if $q$ is even. Consequently, the domain of $f$ is
   $$ \operatorname{dom}(f) = \{ p/q : \text{$p, q \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $\gcd(p, q) = 1$ and $q$ is odd} \}. $$
   This is a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$, so the notion of limit of $f$ can be discussed everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$.
3. For each $p/q \in \operatorname{dom}(f)$ in lowest term, it turns out that
   $$ f(p/q) = (-1)^p (1/2)^{p/q}. $$
   For example
   \begin{align*}
   f(1.92) &= f(48/25) = (-1)^{48}(1/2)^{48/25} \approx 0.264255, \\
   f(1.96) &= f(49/25) = (-1)^{49}(1/2)^{49/25} \approx -0.257028.
   \end{align*}
   (*Note:* If the exponential function is implemented differently in your calculator, the outcome can certainly be different from what $f(t)$ evaluates.)

Under this definition, we can show that $f$ does not have limit at any point. Indeed, this is because both

$$ \{ x \in \operatorname{dom}(f) : f(x) > 0 \} = \{ p/q : \text{$p, q \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $\gcd(p, q) = 1$ and $p$ is even and $q$ is odd} \} $$

and

$$ \{ x \in \operatorname{dom}(f) : f(x) < 0 \} = \{ p/q : \text{$p, q \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $\gcd(p, q) = 1$ and both $p$ and $q$ are odd} \} $$

are dense subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. More precisely, for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$,

$$ \limsup_{\operatorname{dom}(f) \ni t \to x} f(t) = (1/2)^x \qquad \text{and}\qquad \liminf_{\operatorname{dom}(f) \ni t \to x} f(t) = -(1/2)^{x}. $$

Since limsup and liminf are different, the limit cannot exist. (Of course, the non-existence of limit can also be shown by finding subsequences that tend to different values.)

**Remark.** Note that the "real-valued" exponential $f$ is a "maximal" version. However, if we restrict $f$ further onto some dense subset $D$, then the restriction $f|_D$ can possibly have limits. (I suspect that the calculator OP is using implements the exponential in such a way that $(-1/2)^x$ is chosen to be real only on certain subsets of $\operatorname{dom}(f)$. In this case, the answer does depend on that particular implementation of the exponential function.)